# Use of wildcard characters in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard

I need to copy some files from one folder to another using batch file.

The source folder has a registered symbol ( R with a circle around it) in its name. I dont have the rights to rename the folder but I need to trace to the source folder and copy the files in it.

I tried to use the characters . ?  and * which works when I directly run it on command prompt. But when I use it in the batch file, it searches for the file with that character in the name

Please let me know how I can reproduce the registered symbol using keyboard and how I can use wildcards to find the folder name.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have quotation marks around the file name in your batch file.  Remove the quotation marks, and it should then expand properly.

Also, you should modify your question to show exactly what your copy command looks like in your batch file.  It would significantly help myself and others to determine a solution.

Comment: Thanks Brent. 
xcopy /I /Y %Imager_CCVIEW%\njclientapp\rave\Installer\Imager®AWP\AwpRel\PP_incomplete.cfg %DSTPATH% 
is the copy command where Imager_CCVIEW is the environment variable I created pointing to a particular location and DSTPATH is the destination.
The folder Imager®AWP is the one which is causing problems to me as ® symbol(R with a circle around it) reads as _(underscore) in windows 7 and r in windows XP. If you can help me reproduce the symbol or help me use a wildcard for the same it will solve my problem.
I tried the same without quotes ,it still doesnt recognize the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The ® (Registered Mark) is the character number 174 (at least, in Lucida console, the standard font in Windows). You may directly enter it via the keyboard with Alt-174 (in numeric keypad) keystrokes. If this not works, you may copy if from the Character Map accessory and then paste it in any place you wish.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Antonio
>echo Character pasted from Character Map: ®
Character pasted from Character Map: ®
```

Comment: Thank you Aacini , but I need to use a wildcard and not print the ® symbol because the folder is seen differently from different OS. Win 7 - Imager_AWP.. win xp - Imager_AWP. So i need to use wildcard characters.